# BLE characteristic.setValue is setting only with breakpoint

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to toggle the LED of CC2650 Launchpad by writing to the BLE characteristics. It works OK if I set a breakpoint but not under free run.
Here is my code:

```
byte[] characteristicBytesArr = characteristic.getValue();
if (characteristicBytesArr == null) {
    return false;
}
if (characteristicBytesArr[0] == 1) {
    characteristicBytesArr[0] = (byte) (0 & 0xFF);
} else {
    characteristicBytesArr[0] = (byte) (1 & 0xFF);
}
if(characteristic.setValue(characteristicBytesArr)){
    characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}
```

Now, With breakpoint on the line: "`if(characteristic.setValue(characteristicBytesArr)){`" it works OK, but on free run or with breakpoint 2 lines below - nothing happens - the characteristics `mValue` does not change as if `setValue` failed without notice.

Please help

Comment: Did you wait for `onServicesDiscovered` to be called before writing characteristics? Did you perform any write/readCharacteristics or writeDescriptor before writing to your LED characteristic ?

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, The context of the code is after displaying properly the characteristics on a clickable list. The OnChildClickListener has the following code:

Comment: String uid = characteristic.getUuid().toString();
                        if (uid.equals("f0001111-0451-4000-b000-000000000000") || uid.equals("f0001112-0451-4000-b000-000000000000")) {
 ..... that's where my code is running but not performing the setValue

Comment: Got it to run properly by: 1) reading the characteristics using mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic); instead of characteristic.getValue() and 2) handling is done in onCharacteristicRead callBack